# Error correction for windowed reads from cyclic tapes

Tags: coding-theory, encoding-scheme, error-correcting-codes

I have an array of N symbols written on a cyclic tape. I read a sequence of M symbols starting from a random place on the tape. What error correcting scheme and even a coding scheme should I use for such "channel"?

Also will this problem  be simpler if tape is not cyclic?

Comment: Do you want an optimal scheme or just something simple that's likely to work reasonably well in practice?

Comment: @D.W. I need practical solution, which will be not so hard to implement.

Comment: I'm thinking about using "start of the message" symbol with Reed–Solomon code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned [in a comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136080/error-correction-for-windowed-reads-from-cyclic-tapes#comment291858_136112) that your messages are very short, only 7-10 bits long.  Another option is to explicitly construct a code, with encoding and decoding done via a lookup table rather than by an algorithm or a formula.

For instance, suppose you have $K=7$-bit messages, that you will encode to a $N=30$-bit codeword that will be written onto the tape, and then you'll read $M=13$ bits starting from somewhere on the tape.  Let $p(c)$ denote the set of $M$-bit sequences that could be read if $c$ was the codeword on the tape, i.e., $p(c)$ is the set of all $M$-bit sequences of $c$ (i.e., the $M$-bit prefixes of all cyclical shifts of $c$).  Let $e(m)$ denote the encoding of the 7-bit message $m$; we'll construct $e$ below.  Consider the following algorithm to choose a lookup table for $e$:

1. Let $S := \emptyset$.
2. For each $K$-bit message $m$:

   a. Pick $c$ randomly from all $N$-bit sequences such that $p(c)$ has no overlap with $S$.

   b. Let $e(m) := c$ and $S := S \cup p(c)$.

If the algorithm gets stuck, then go back to step 1 and restart.  When this algorithm finishes, it will built up an encoder $e$, as a lookup table; you can then build up a decoder as follows:

3. For each $K$-bit message $m$:

   - For each $s \in e(m)$, set $d(s) := m$.

One inefficient way to implement step 2a is with [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling): pick $c$ randomly from $\{0,1\}^N$, compute $p(c)$, and check whether it has any intersection with $S$; if there's no intersection, then keep it, otherwise repeat with a new $c$.  The probability that a randomly chosen $c$ is acceptable will be about $(1 - N / 2^{M-K})^N$ (or higher) in each step, so for some parameter choices this might be OK, but with others, it might be too slow.

Another (possibly faster) way to implement step 2a is to choose $c$ bit-by-bit.  In more detail:

1. For $i:=1,2,\dots,N$:

   - Pick $c_i$ randomly.
   - If $c_{i-M+1},\dots,c_{i-1},c_i \in S$:

     - Flip $c_i$.  If $c_{i-M+1},\dots,c_{i-1},c_i \in S$, discard $c_1,\dots,c_i$ and go back to step 1, starting over from the beginning (starting with $i=1$).

A third way to implement step 2a, if $N$ is not too large, is to build a giant bitvector that stores the subset $T$ of $\{0,1\}^N$ of safe $N$-bit sequences, i.e., the subset $T = \{c \in \{0,1\}^N : p(C) \cap S = \emptyset\}$.  Each time we add some value, call it $s$, to $S$ in step 2b, we can remove all $N$-bit values that contain $s$ as a substring from $T$.  There will be $N \times 2^{N-M}$ such values to remove from $T$.  Then, step 2a amounts to picking randomly from $T$.  This will be inefficient if $N$ is large, though, and I'm not sure it has any advantages over the second way.

If you have a set value of $K$ and $N$, you'll probably have to experiment with different values of $M$ to see what is the smallest value for which you can construct an explicit code in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this problem has been studied, and I bet there will be better solutions, but I'll suggest a scheme that I suspect might work well enough, even if it's not optimal.

## Naive approach: brute-force decoding

I would bet that any [erasure code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasure_code) would work, if combined with brute-force decoding.  For decoding, I am imagining that a naive algorithm is to enumerate all possibilities for what the starting point was, decode under that assumption, and check whether it leads to a correct reconstruction that is consistent with that assumption (i.e., all symbols you read match).  Heuristically, I would expect that typically there will be only one decoding that is consistent with the observed data.  This might be a bit slow -- decoding might take $O(MN)$ time for many codes, because of need to try all $O(N)$ possibilities for the starting point -- but if that's acceptable, it should be something that's easy to implement.

For instance, you could use a [Reed-Solomon code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction).  To encode a message, you treat it as a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree less than $M$ (say, of degree $M-1-\lg N$) over some finite field (i.e., the bits of the message determine the coefficients of $p(x)$).  Then, you write $p(\alpha^i)$ in the $i$th position on the tape, for $i=1,2,\dots,N$ (where $\alpha$ is a fixed element of the finite field).  For each guess at where the read symbols might have started from, you can decode using polynomial interpolation.  The entire procedure will take $O(MN \log M)$ time, to decode.

## Faster approach: rolling hash

Here is an alternative that should be me faster: it runs in linear time.  I expect it will be close to optimal.

**Encoding algorithm.**  Let $C$ be a small constant, to be chosen later.  Let's suppose we have a message that is $M-C$ symbols long.  We'll compute a [Rabin-Karp rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash) of the message, a hash that is $C$ symbols long, and append it to the message.  Then, we'll repeat these $M$ symbols cyclically, to get a $N$-symbol word.  That will be the codeword that is the encoding of the message.  Encoding can be done in $O(N)$ time.

**Decoding algorithm.** Given an observed value $Y$ with $M$ symbols, we'll try all $M$ possibilities for cyclically shifting it to see which is correct.  We can recognize when we have the correct shift because the last $C$ symbols will be the valid hash of the first $M-C$ symbols.

Naively, this decoding procedure would take $O(M^2)$ time.  However, we can use the properties of the Rabin-Karp rolling hash to make decoding much more efficient.  Let $H(x)$ denote the Rabin-Karp hash of $x$.  Note that we can apply the Rabin-Karp rolling hash to $Y$ and learn $H(Y_{1..i})$ for each $i$; we can compute all $M$ of these hashes in $O(M)$ time.
From $H(Y_{1..i-1})$ and $H(Y_{1..j})$, we can compute $H(Y_{i..j})$ in $O(1)$ time. Also, given two hashes $H(x_1)$ and $H(x_2)$, we can compute the hash $H(x_1||x_2)$ of the concatenation of $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $O(1)$ time.  Thus, for any candidate cyclical shift of $Y$, we can compute the hash of the first $M-C$ symbols in $O(1)$ time, given the precomputed values $H(Y_{1..i})$, and thereby check whether this candidate shift is correct (by comparing that hash to the last $C$ symbols of the shifted value).  This decoding algorithm does an initial $O(M)$-time precomputation to compute all of the $H(Y_{1..i})$ values, and then checks $M$ candidates, each of which takes $O(1)$ time, for a total decoding time of $O(M)$.

**Choosing parameters.** Lastly, I need to describe how we choose the constant $C$.  I suggest choosing it so that it is very unlikely that any incorrect decoding will survive the hash-value check.  Suppose each symbol is $b$ bits long.  Then, a $C$-symbol hash is $bC$ bits long, and each incorrect candidate shift has a $1/2^{bC}$ chance of being wrongly accepted (by having the hash value match just by sheer chance).  We test $M$ candidate shifts, so there is about a $M/2^{bC}$ chance that one of these is wrongly accepted.  We might set as a goal that this chance should be at most $1/2^{50}$ (so that the chance of wrongly accepting an invalid message is less than the chance of being struck by lightning multiple times, and less than the chance of a cosmic ray hitting your computer and causing a bitflip error, i.e., negligibly small).  This means we need $M/2^{bC} \le 1/2^{50}$, so it suffices to take $C = \lceil(50 + \lg M)/b \rceil$.

Comment: Thank you! I understood that with Reed-Solomon I actually don't need the "begin of the message" symbol, which is great! Also, can I somehow guess erasures or, better rely only on error correction?

Comment: @Moonwalker, I edited my answer to add a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: I'm experimenting with LDPC codes and my decoder decodes all permutations. Is there something in LDPC construction which differs from Reed Solomon?

Comment: I have a very short message of 7-10 bits, and I could not put it into Reed Solomon codes, because the usual symbols for RS are 2^m and libraries are not supporting alphabets with m < 3

Comment: @Moonwalker, when you say "permutations", do you mean "cyclic shifts"?  There are n! permutations but n cyclic shifts.  After the decoder decodes, did you do the extra step to "check whether it leads to a correct reconstruction that is consistent with that assumption (i.e., all symbols you read match)"?  One way to do that is decode, then re-encode and check that the result is the same as what you tried to decode.

Comment: Yes, cyclic shifts, indeed.

Comment: @Moonwalker, I added another answer as well.

Comment: Sorry for being so understanding, but I cannot get the idea of decode then reencode approach: the reencoding won't give me something different from what I've guessed https://dpaste.org/MGC8 

and bch being cyclic it means cyclic shifted array is of course a valid input

Comment: @Moonwalker, ok, well, it's always possible I have made a mistake or missed something.  If you tried it and it doesn't work, maybe it just doesn't work.